# Adicionar botões na célula do DataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Windows Form C# de controle de atividades de uma empresa, entretanto eu precisaria exibir as atividades como **botões** dentro da célula do `GridView`.

Já tentei:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn uninstallButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
uninstallButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
uninstallButtonColumn.HeaderText = "Delete/Edit";
uninstallButtonColumn.Name = "uninstall_column";
uninstallButtonColumn.Text = "Teste";

dgvPrincipal.Columns.Insert(1, uninstallButtonColumn);
```

Este formato permite apenas *1* botão, quando na verdade podem existir vários botões em uma mesma celula.

E já tentei também:

```
dgvPrincipal.Rows[0].Cells[0].DataGridView.Controls.Add(tbnTeste);
```

Este insere o botão sem vinculo algum com as células..

Alguém conhece algum caminho? Tipo `DataRowBound`... ou algo parecido?

Comment: Por que nao coloca os botões em outra coluna?

Comment: [Nesse link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.90).aspx) tem um exemplo que pode te dar uma direção a ser seguida.

Answer (score 2):

No meu caso isso resolveu meu problema...

Você pode apenas usar um `DataGridViewImageColumn` e utilizar o evento `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` para verificar qual célula foi clicada.

**Obs**: No meu caso, eu estava precisando de dois botões em meu `DataGridView`, 
   sendo um para editar o conteúdo selecionado e outro para excluir o item da 
   linha selecionada.

- ***Passo 1:*** 
    Você deve adicionar 2 colunas no seu `Grid`, e setá-las como 
    `DataGridViewImageColumn`. Adicione as imagens requeridas em cada campo.
- ***Passo 2:*** 
    Vá até os eventos do `Grid` e dê um duplo-clique sobre o campo
    `CellContentClick` ou `CellClick`. Tanto faz um ou outro a diferença é
    que o primeiro só irá ser utilizado se o usuário **clicar sobre a
    imagem** dentro da célula. Já a segunda irá funcionar quando o usuário
    **clicar sobre a célula inteira**.
- ***Passo 3:***
    No evento do `DataGridView`, escreva o código abaixo:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado...

Se te ajudou, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta.

Grande Abraço!

Comment: Pablo, se possível [**edite a resposta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/149405/edit) e coloque o código aqui! *+1*

Answer (score -1):

private void tablePericiaDocs_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
{
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Abre formulário para realizar a edição...");

```
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            MessageBoxButtons button = (MessageBoxButtons)MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
    
            MessageBoxIcon alerta = MessageBoxIcon.Warning;

            if (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(this, "Tem certeza que deseja excluir permanentemente este item?", "AVISO", button, alerta) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                tablePericiaDocs.Rows.RemoveAt(tablePericiaDocs.CurrentRow.Index);

            }
```